# Is there a way to avoid repetition of generic type parameters when one type could be inferred from the other?

Tags: java, generics

This is a contrived example, but simpler to explain than my actual code:

```
public interface ContainerOwner<T, C extends Container<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to avoid the repetition of `T` in that type signature because it becomes unwieldy when the parameters themselves have parameters, for example:

```
ContainerOwner<
     Optional<Future<Map<String, Integer>>>,
     List<Optional<Future<Map<String, Integer>>>>
> foo;
```

In this example, I feel like the first parameter could be inferred from the second. Is there a trick to do that?

Comment: How are you using the types?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm not quite sure what you mean with your question.

Comment: Show the code that uses the types. Maybe you don't need the type(s)!

Comment: Ah. I can't post the actual code (in part because it's at my office and I am not!). I will try to expand the contrived example so that it captures some of what I'm trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use a more specific sub-interface that will need **only one** type parameter, something like:

```
public interface ListOwner<T> extends ContainerOwner<T, List<T>> {
}
```

Then your code would be:

```
ListOwner<Optional<Future<Map<String, Integer>>>> foo;
```

Comment: Thanks. In a lot of cases this will work, but it is quite constraining: `ListOwner<T>` is a subtype of the type I want, not an alias to it. I was looking for a solution similar to type aliases in Rust or Haskell, or something like you can get with Haskell functional dependencies, which Rust can  approximate with associated types. It seems that [Scala has some support for functional dependencies](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/) so I'll maybe try that out instead.